# Condição Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, condição, macro

Nesta [worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmGQ4.png) eu tenho uma tabela em que sempre que qualquer célula da coluna do meio é alterada é executado um certo [macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0RmB.png). Eu queria que, por exemplo quando alterasse a célula E12 o valor que eu pusesse na janela fosse escrito na célula F12, e quando alterasse a célula E10 o valor que eu pusesse na janela fosse escrito na célula F10 e por aí fora. É possível fazer isso? É que neste momento só consigo com que escreva numa célula ou então que escreva tudo igual num certo intervalo de células.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Esse evento (Worksheet_Change) está avaliando se o 'Target' (uma célula, neste caso) está contida no intervalo de interesse (E5:E32). Isto significa que o 'Target' será um endereço variável, cuja linha pode variar de 5 a 32. Assim, na coluna F, você tem que colocar a resposta na mesma linha do 'Target'. Target.Row é o número da linha que você precisa endereçar na coluna F: (adicionei uma avaliação da entrada feita, de forma a só aceitar datas corretamente informadas)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyValue As Variant
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5:E32")) Is Nothing Then
        MyValue = InputBox("Em que data foi assistida?", "Aviso", "Digite Aqui:")
        If IsDate(MyValue) Then
            Range("F" & Target.Row).Value = MyValue
        Else
           MsgBox "Data inválida. Verifique."
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```